# How to find the element id when a draggable enters the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am having a draggable and I need to know the id to which the draggable element enters.

There is a draggable div.
It can be moved over table.
I need to get the id of the td over which the draggable is kept.

I am out of idea. Can anybody help me?

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
            init: function(element) {
                $(element).draggable({
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var stopPos = $(this).position();
                    },
                    containment : 'body'
                });
            }
    };
```

Comment: Where are your ideas? Cannot see even one... Post what you have tried!

Comment: No. Its very big code. I cannot post all. I have made it draggable.

Comment: Post your failed attempt, if any...

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`over`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) event to know the current overed td id of your table.

Code:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();

$("td").droppable({
    over: function (ev, ui) {
        console.log(this.id)
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/aTV5T/

Answer (score 1):

do you need to know the `id` of the element over which the `draggable` element is `dropped`?

you need to register the `drop` function on the `droppable`(in your case, the table),

this is how you can get both the `id` of the `droppable` and the `draggable`

```
$('.selector').droppable({ drop: Drop });

function Drop(event, ui) {
  var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
  var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
}
```